# How can I get package name  in android?

Tags: java, android

I need to write some util class by myself and I need the packagename of android app.
While I found the packageManager which only can be used in Activity and so on that has context. I only want to get packagename in my class which will be used in android app. So how can I do this? Thank you!

Comment: do u need all installed application's package name?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Use : `getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 0).packageName`
Or just `MyContext.getPackageName()`

You can also create a function:

```
public String getPackageName(Context context) {
    return context.getPackageName();
}
```

Comment: thank you,maybe I didn't describe clearly，It's an ordinary class,so it hasn't Context.The class will be packaged in a jar which used in android app.So I can't get method to reach it.

Comment: So create a function like that :
    `MyFunction(Context MyContext){
        MyContext.getPackageName()
    }`

Comment: `String pkg_name = getApplicationContext().getPackageName()`

Answer (score 20):

The following constant is available without the need for a context.

```
BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID
```

Answer (score 4):

you can get the package name of installed app:

```
ArrayList<PackageInfo> res = new ArrayList<PackageInfo>();
        PackageManager pm = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager();
        List<PackageInfo> packs = pm.getInstalledPackages(0);
```

and if you want to find the package name of your app:

```
context.getPackageName();
```

Comment: thank you,maybe I didn't describe clearly，It's an ordinary class,so it hasn't Context.The class will be packaged in a jar which used in android app.So I can't get method to reach it.thank you all,but all of your answer is same.

Answer (score 2):

`getApplicationContext().getPackageName()` will give the package name.

Comment: why? Always give the reason if you are asked someone not to use it. I also don't know why you asked not to use this.

Comment: This will retrieve the wrong package name. See my answer below to always get the correct `java` package name. Your answer can be modified by gradle thus producing “inaccurate” package names (I.e. it’ll say debug, release, or whatever build flavor you have set up)

Answer (score 1):

```
List<ApplicationInfo> packages;
    PackageManager pm;
    pm = getPackageManager();
             get a list of installed apps.
            packages = pm.getInstalledApplications(0);

ActivityManager mActivityManager = (ActivityManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);

   for (ApplicationInfo packageInfo : packages) {
   //packageInfo.packageName contains package name


                      }
```

Comment: thank you,maybe I didn't describe clearly，It's an ordinary class,so it hasn't Context.The class will be packaged in a jar which used in android app.So I can't get method to reach it.thank you all,but all of your answer is same.

Comment: then you can send a reference to the context and can use that this way

Answer (score 1):

you can create a Util Class this way:

```
public class AppInfo{
  private static Context cxt;
  public static String PACKAGE_INFO;
  public static String init(Context context){
    cxt = context;
    PACKAGE_INFO = cxt.getPackageName();
  }
}
```

then you can use it this way

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity{
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle bundle){
    ...
    AppInfo.init(getApplicationContext());
    ...
  }
}
```

then you can call it this way:

```
public class someClass{
  public void someMethod(){
    String packageInfo = AppInfo.PACKAGE_INFO;
    //Do what you wish
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have seen the following two ways to get the package name starting from a Context variable:

```
context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(context.getPackageName(), 0).packageName
```

and

```
context.getPackageName()
```

Won't they always give the same answer?  Is one way preferable to use over the other in certain circumstances?

Answer (score 1):

Here add this to your util class. It makes sure to handle different “flavors” and debug/release builds, as other answers do not:

```
@Nullable
public static String getApplicationPackageName(@NonNull Context context)
{
    final PackageInfo packageInfo = getPackageInfo(context);
    if (packageInfo.applicationInfo == null)
    {
        return null;
    }
    // Returns the correct “java” package name that was defined in your
    // AndroidManifest.xml.
    return packageInfo.applicationInfo.packageName;
}

// Convenience method for getting the applications package info.
@NonNull
private static PackageInfo getPackageInfo(@NonNull final Context context)
{
    final PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();

    try
    {
        return packageManager.getPackageInfo(context.getPackageName(), 0);
    }
    catch (final PackageManager.NameNotFoundException ignored)
    {
        //noinspection ConstantConditions: packageInfo should always be available for the embedding app.
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't easier with `BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID`? What cases doesn't cover?

Comment: Because of different build variants/flavors and also Gradle 8.0 is moving to namespaces rather than packages, which will probably affect all of this.

Answer (score 0):

I think  `getPackageName()` is available directly within activity without calling `getApplicationContext`. Checked it myself.Working good.