# Get absolute path of android drawable image

Tags: android, path, drawable

I need to get the absolute path or the File object of my drawable image in android application. Is there any way to do this?

Drawable is as following

context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.back_button)

Comment: by drawable id i has taken the Drawable object. i need to get the absolute path of that

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8601070/android-get-image-path-from-drawable-as-string

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you app is insalled on sdcard  try this code :

```
Bitmap bitMap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.id.img1);

File mFile1 = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

String fileName ="img1.jpg";

File mFile2 = new File(mFile1,fileName);
try {
       FileOutputStream outStream;

       outStream = new FileOutputStream(mFile2);

       bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, outStream);

       outStream.flush();

       outStream.close();

} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
       // TODO Auto-generated catch block
       e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
       // TODO Auto-generated catch block
       e.printStackTrace();
}

String sdPath = mFile1.getAbsolutePath().toString()+"/"+fileName;

Log.i("hiya", "Your IMAGE ABSOLUTE PATH:-"+sdPath); 

File temp=new File(sdPath);

if(!temp.exists()){
       Log.e("file","no image file at location :"+sdPath);
}
```

Answer (score 7):

```
Uri path = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.nikhil.material/" + R.drawable.image);
```

OR

```
Uri otherPath = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.nikhil.material/drawable/image");
```

OR

```
Uri path = Uri.parse("android.resource://"+BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID+"/" + R.drawable.image);
```

Comment: maybe use `BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID` like `Uri.parse("android.resource://"+BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID+"/" + R.drawable.image);` idea from -> http://stackoverflow.com/a/29109743/1815624

Answer (score 2):

drawable resources are added to binary at run time therefore cannot be accessed by path.
you can decode and use drawables instead.

If you need resources you can access at runtime by path, try using assets folder instead.

Hope this is helpful