# Absolute path of a drawable in android

Tags: android, android-drawable, absolute-path

I am running shell command where i want to use some images which I have put in res/drawable folder. To run this in shell, i need to pass absolute path. 
So is there anyway to get the absolute path for this?

I checked 
[Get absolute path of android drawable image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25758159/get-absolute-path-of-android-drawable-image)

but this is also not working.

Comment: what shell command do you mean? where do you run it?

Comment: Shell command? What tool are you using? Is it in mobile app ?

Comment: I want to use ffmpeg. I am using java wrapper library for that, inside that it is using shell command. so for that i need to pass the path for resource images.

Comment: no resources can be a accessed outside your app as they are not mapped to a physical file system

Answer (score 0):

its not possible to get path of drawable image directly , but you can get this by storing it in internal memory or sdcard of device. For this check out the link
[here](http://maulik-dhameliya.blogspot.in/2013/03/how-to-get-absolute-path-of-drawable.html)

**Why** **Not possible** **directly**

When you compile your app to an *.apk file, all resources (ok, except from them in /raw) are compiled as well. You can only acces them, using their R. id.