# How to get application name in android?

Tags: android

when an app is being install in device and after success. I have to get that app package name and from package name i have to identify "App name". How can I do that

code:-

```
private String TAG = CAppReceiver.class.getSimpleName();
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String action = intent.getAction();
    if (action.equals("android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED")){
        Log.d(TAG,"App package::" + intent.getData().toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried via the PackageManager?

Comment: see [recieve broadcast when app installed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11246326/how-to-receiving-broadcast-when-application-installed-or-removed) see [get application name from package name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5841161/get-application-name-from-package-name)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7090883/how-can-i-get-package-name-in-android

Comment: Where and how are you registering the receiver?

Comment: getPackageName();  use this and using split method you can  separate application name from package.

Comment: @SorathiyaPayal package name can be completely different from app name. FYI

Answer (score 1):

```
 String pakageName =getPackageName();
 String[] separated = pakageName.split(".");
 separated[0]; 
 separated[1];
```

hear code for get application name ,first get package name and than split it to get application name.

Answer (score 0):

In your manifest, add a receiver with the relevant intent service (inside application tag):

```
<receiver android:name=".apps.AppListener">
    <intent-filter android:priority="100">
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_INSTALL"/>
         <data android:scheme="package"/> 
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

According to google doc's:

> PACKAGE_INSTALL Broadcast Action: A new
>   application package has been installed on the device. The data
>   contains the name of the package. Note that the newly installed
>   package does not receive this broadcast.

Then use your onReceive code method.

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;

public class AppListener extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.v(TAG, "there is a broadcast");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the below Method to get the Application package name.

```
intent.getData().getSchemeSpecificPart()
```

and use below code to get other application specific information.

```
 try {
    ApplicationInfo app = this.getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo("com.example.name", 0);        

    Drawable icon = packageManager.getApplicationIcon(app);
    String name = packageManager.getApplicationLabel(app);
    return icon;
} catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "error in getting icon", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    toast.show();
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get your your app name or application label if you have the package name. Here is how

```
PackageManager packageManager= getApplicationContext().getPackageManager();
String appName = (String) packageManager.getApplicationLabel(packageManager.getApplicationInfo("YourPackageName", PackageManager.GET_META_DATA));
```