# how to get the package name of android messaging App?

Tags: android, package, android-developer-api, package-name

I want to get a package name of android messaging application which works with every android device brands like now I'm testing on samsung A31 and it's package name is "com.samsung.android.messaging" but it only works with samsung phones.
Is there any default sms app for android which works on every brand.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I get package name  in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7090883/how-can-i-get-package-name-in-android)

Comment: @SwetaJain No, that's not for getting the messaging app's package name.

Answer (score 0):

To get the package name of default sms app, use the following code

```
// add import
import android.provider.Telephony;
//get the package name
String packageName = Telephony.Sms.getDefaultSmsPackage(context);
```

Comment: my question is not that how to get a package names i have that package name of samsung messaging app but i want my app to work with all devices.

Comment: @SyedFidaullahShah Is that working for you?